# Python Selenium get <source> from Video tag

Tags: python, selenium

So i want to create a python application which downloads images & videos from instagram-stories. The images are no problem, but the videos are. Because the src isnt't simply in the video. Instead it is like this:

```
<video class="FOO" ....... autoplay>
    <source src="BAR" .....>
</video>
```

I adressed it in the following code, but it doesnt work:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('video').getAttribute('source')
```

And i also tried:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('video').getAttribute('src')
```

And i tried:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('video').find_element_by_tag_name('source').getAttribute('src')
```

Last but not least i changed the 'element' to 'elements', but it did not work.
But none of it works.
I made it with and without try/except, but when i did it without it doesn't give me a exception, it just exits, and when i did it with, it just goes to the catched exception.
So how do i have to adress the source tag?

UPDATE:
I changed it to:
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('source').get_attribute("src")
then it worked!
Thanks to everyone, who helped me

Comment: Which site are you scraping, may the elements are not available yet unless it would work.

Comment: first check if you can get `<video>`. Maybe video is in `<frame.` and then you have to use `switch_to.frame(...)`. But bette put url in question so we could see this page.

Comment: @RajivShah Im scraping instagram-stories

Comment: @MrMassachusetts, hi. 2 questions:

Comment: @MrMassachusetts, hi. 2 questions:  (1) what exception You face when You execute the code without  try/except  block?     (2) what does the following piece of code print for You:  `listofvideos = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//video/source")`
`for item in listofvideos:`
    `print (item.get_attribute("src"))`

Comment: I got it by myself: i changed it to: driver.find_element_by_tag_name('source').get_attribute("src") But thanks to everyone, who helped!

Answer (score 1):

Update right here:
I changed it to:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('source').get_attribute("src")
```

and then it worked.
Thanks to everyone helping